# UITest popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am not sure if this is good practice or not, so feel free to call me out if it's not. I have a UI test which is designed to test my welcome screen for my app. So in the test I wanted to put an if statement to make sure I am in the correct view controller before the test code runs. My issue is if I am not in the correct View Controller I wanted to pop it to the root view controller and run the test from there but I am not sure how to do so.

In other words if I am not on the Welcome VC then move me there and run the test.
What is the syntax for doing this in a UI Test? Currently what I tried is  to  write

```
else { 
 UINavigationController.popToRootViewController("WelcomeScreenNavigationController")
 run the rest of the test from the welcome vc....
}
```

the "WelcomeScreenNavigationController" is the storyboard id of my nav controller.
The error I get when I try to pop to my root controller this way is 
[image]

If anyone knows how I could get back to the root VC to properly run my UITest that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call the `popToRootViewController` function on the `UINavigationController` class, rather than an instance of that class. The function is an instance method and must be called on an instance.